# Rails 3 api - Locations of most common methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails (3). I would like to study some of the docs more thoroughly, but I am having a problem locating them.

Under which namespaces do I find the most common methods for tasks dealing with Views, Controllers, Migrations and Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api documentation could be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org

- views: `ActionView::Helpers`
- controllers: `ActionController` and its modules
- migrations: `ActiveRecord::Migration`
- models: `ActiveRecord::Base` and its modules